# How can I programmatically determine the time a Gmail label was applied to a message?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

How can I programmatically determine the date/time a message in Gmail had a label applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, label application time is not available via the Gmail API.

Out of curiosity, why do you need this information?

Comment: My use case is really kooky.  I use Gmail as a reading list; basically I have two labels - "to read" and "read" (as in past tense).  I send a link to Gmail and it gets the "to read" label.  Two weeks later I read the document and move it to the "read" label.  Some time after that, I want to go back and see something about what I read.  I remember the rough day I read it, the message data is of corse the date it got received by gmail, which has nothing to do with when I read it.  So I was hoping there would be metadata allowing me to see when the "read" label was applied.